# Customers are unable to attach/upload a File after a Live Agent has Initiated a File Transfer During a Chat Session

Tags: community, liveagent, chat, embedded-services, livechattranscript

we are running into an issue with our customers unable to attach files after a file transfer has been initiated by **Live Agent**. The request has been passed to customer but when the customer uploads the file it stops in the middle and not uploaded. Has anyone run into this before and have any guidance on how to resolve?

Related Article: [enter link description here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.live_agent_transfer_files.htm&type=5)

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We resolved this issue after adding the salesforce platform Domain URL to CSP settings

setup --> Domains --> My Domain

Add My Domain at setup -->CSP